# Openfire and push notifications

Tags: php, push, apple-push-notifications, openfire

I am writing an IOS app that is basically a jabber chat app. I am using Openfire for the xmpp server and so far its been great. The problem I am facing now is with push notifications. The app is written in Xcode which gets user data from a PHP Api. Openfire is the xmpp server. The issue is that when the app sends a message to openfire I would need to also query the Php api to see if the user is online and if they are not, send a push notification. This would have to happen for each message sent and as you might guess that will affect performance with all those requests happening.

I have everything working, I just cant get past this hump. If only openfire would fife off a request of my choice upon receiving a message.

Can anyone suggest a better idea?  Basically need to know if the user is online (presence) before so that I know to fire off the push notification and I dont want to fire off two requests from my app per message sent. Thanks.

Comment: Could you please add a more detailed answer what you have done with the openfire code please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In openfire the messages to offline users are stored in ofoffline table. So your php code neednot worry about the status of the user if der is any entry in the ofOfline table it means the user was offline. Now create a scheduler that will keep looking in the ofOfline table for offline messages club them together and push notification  to the user

Comment: Sorry I didnt accept your answer in a more timely manner. I did end up using your solution and it worked wonderfully.

Comment: Hi pogeybait,
Nice to to see things worked for you ..hope can help you further in solving the issues

Comment: @Vivek Giri what do you mean by a scheduler - an openfire java code or a database scheduler?

Comment: Hi @user1054134 being a java developer I had used  spring based scheduler that used to keep track of the ofOfline table.

Comment: @VivekGiri can you tell of open-fire which plugin or other way to pass push notification for offline user send message? beacuse i don't know about sever side( Openfire - xmpp server) , client side(ios) try each way but not get success.

Comment: @VivekGiri you dont need to create a scheduler for sending offline notification to person to person messages callbackonoffline plugin (https://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins.jsp) will do the job for you.. But what is the solution for group messages, offline messages are also stored on offmessagearchive table there is no group offline table available for group chat. Is there any plugin available for sending offline notification?

Answer (score 0):

i have spen lots of time for in XAMPPHP Library but cant find any proper solution. so for develop a web base chat application with jabber server. rather than using XAMPPHP, you can use "http://strophe.im/strophejs/" it will be much faster than XAMPPHP and you can find more js plugin for Strophe js. and you can also find more ready made xmpp client base on strophe js. so it will better than XAMPHP.